# CoreText.framework: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode

When i built a xcode project with CoreText.framework, but get the following error.

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework: No such file or directory.

At the same time, there is 
"iPhoneOS.sdk" and "iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -> iPhoneOS.sdk", below /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs only.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.

Because i added the framework into "Embedded Binaries".